# Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I try to make API on django-rest-framework:

models.py

```
class ArticleCategory(SystemModel):
    name =          models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=255)
    category_slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=False)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

class ArticleItem(SystemModel):
    name =              models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=255)
    item_slug =         models.SlugField(blank=True, null=False)
    text =              models.TextField(blank=True)
    article_category =  models.ForeignKey('article.ArticleCategory', blank=False, null=False, related_name='article_item_set')
```

serializers.py

```
class ArticleCategorySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    article_items = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField('article_item_set', view_name='article:item')
    class Meta:
        model =     ArticleCategory
        fields =    ('url', 'name', 'category_slug', 'article_items',)

class ArticleItemSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    article_category = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField('article_category', view_name='article:category')
    class Meta:
        model =     ArticleItem
        fields =    ('url', 'name', 'item_slug', 'text', 'article_category')
```

urls.py

```
#namespace='article'
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<item_slug>[\w-]+)', ArticleItemDetail.as_view(), name='item'),
   url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[\w-]+)', ArticleItemListByCategory.as_view(), name='category'),
   url(r'^', ArticleItemList.as_view(), name='item-list')
)
```

and api.py

```
class ArticleItemDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    model = ArticleItem
    serializer_class = ArticleItemSerializer
    lookup_field = 'article_slug'

class ArticleItemListByCategory(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = ArticleItem
    serializer_class = ArticleItemSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(ArticleItemListByCategory, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(article_category__category_slug=self.kwargs.get('category_slug'))
```

When i try to get item-list (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/article/`), i get error

> Exception at /article/
>
> Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name
>   "articleitem-detail". You may have failed to include the related model
>   in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on
>   this field.

How to resolve this problem? I want to save this url-structure and in the same time have url-field for every objects:

Article item

```
{
    "name": "Article item 1",
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1/article/article-category-1/article-item-1",
    "item_slug": "article-item-1",
    "text": "\u0432\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0432\u043b\u043e",
    "article_category": {
        "name": "Article category 1",
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1/article/article-category-1",
    }
},
```

Article category

```
{
    "name": "Article category 1",
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1/article/article-category-1",
    "category_slug": "article-category-1",
    "text": "\u0432\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0432\u043b\u043e",
    "article_items": [
        {
            "name": "Article item 1",
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1/article/article-category-1/article-item-1",
        },
        {
            "name": "Article item 2",
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1/article/article-category-1/article-item-2",
        },
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Your lookup field is pointing to `article_slug` that is not present in the database. It should be actually `item_slug`. This seems to be causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

### Change the articleitem detail name in your urls.py

---

Try changing it to this

```
   `url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<item_slug>[\w-]+)', ArticleItemDetail.as_view(), name='articleitem-detail'),`
```

It solved mine.

Comment: Thanks, this was a big help